# Get device date and time in react native. new Date() is not equal to device date and time

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to setup a timeout using setTimeout in react native, but if the device time is greater than the new Date(), then the setTimeout will not work as expected. So i want to get the device date and time. How to get the Device date and time

i tried using various libraries none of the seems to work, 
react-native-clock-sync.
react-native-timer-native

```
setInterval( () => {
  this.setState({
    curDate : new Date().getTime(),
    curDateString : new Date().toLocaleString(),
  })
},1000);
```

my device time is showing as 12:19
when i doing a new Date to get current time I'm getting 12:15

Comment: How do you render the date ?

Comment: i tried both getTime() and new Date().toLocaleString(),